# Iterate through collections and .Add

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, collections

I'm trying to store the `foreach` loop collection of data outside the loop for later use.

Consider the following `foreach` loop.

```
IList<DetailViewModel> storeAllLoopItems = new List<DetailViewModel>();

foreach (var item in _listOfItems)
{
   var items =
   (from a in context.Employee
       join b in context.Orders on a.Id equals b.Id
       join d in context.Notes on a.Id equals d.Id                            
       where a.Id == item.id
       select new DetailViewModel
       {
         Name = b.LegalName,
         Abbrev = c.Abbrev,
         TaxAmount = a.Amount,
       }).ToList();

      storeAllLoopItems.Add(items); //<<<ERROR
}
```

Error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(DetailViewModel)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'DetailViewModel'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` method is for adding a single value.  You will need to add the items into the list by hand, because the `IList` interface has no `AddRange` method.  Or change the definition to be `List<DetailValueModel>` which has an `AddRange` method.

Aslo, the `.ToList()` is not required and wastes memory.

Comment: @GrantWinney, I'm assuming the final statement is `storeAllLoopItems.AddRange(items);`

Comment: `ToList()` is required I'm using EF, just FYI